# How to solve the differential equation: $y-xy'=\exp(y')$

Tags: calculus, differential

> $$y-xy'=\exp(y')$$

I want to solve this differential equation, which looks simple but hard to solve. Any method?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematics.

Comment: What makes it look easy ? I find it terrible !

Answer (score 5):

Use [Clairaut equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation) to find the solution.

The general solution is
$$y(x)=Cx+e^{C}.$$

**Proof from Wikipedia article.**

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$
$$y'=y'+xy''+\exp\left(y'\right)y'',$$
so
$$\left[x+\exp\left(y'\right)\right]y'' = 0.$$

*General solution:*
$$y'' = 0 \Longrightarrow y(x)=Cx+e^C.$$

*Singular solution:*
$$x+\exp\left(y'\right) = 0.$$

---

Thank you @zwim: [Desmos calculator.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8qwne6azhx)

[image: Clairaut equation]

Comment: Is this solution unique? What about the singular solution?

Comment: Can we solve a new differential equation, that is, y-x^2=exp(y'),  using the same method?

Comment: Note that $y-x^2=\exp(y')$ is not a  Clairaut equation.

Comment: How should it be solved then?

Comment: which has a similar form

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no trivial closed form solution for your new ODE.

Comment: @LexintonAve the form of your new equation doesn't fit the form of a Clairaut equation, which are equations of the form $y = xy'+f(y')$ for some continuously differentiable $f$. So $y-xy'=\exp(y')$ or $y-xy'=(y')^2$, etc. are Clairaut but $y-x^2=\exp(y')$ is not. So although the forms look "similar" they are actually very different.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the envelop of family {$cx+e^c$,$c$} and singular solution $x\ln(-x)-x$ graph on your post.